# How to create an isolated/jailed SFTP user?

Tags: ssh, sshd, sftp, chroot

I just created a new user `friend` on my server, the goal is to give SFTP access to a friend of mine, so that he can host his website there.

I noticed that when connecting the server by SFTP with user `friend`, the default folder is `/home/friend/`, but you can easily go out of `/home/friend/` **and visit all files in read access on the server**, such as `/home/anotheruser/website2/config.php`! I don't want this.

I was told to put this user in "jailed / isolated mode", so, at the  end of my default `sshd_config`:

```
...
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

... I added this:

```
Match User friend
ChrootDirectory /home/friend
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

and did `service sshd restart`.

Then I could not connect anymore the server at all by SFTP with user `friend`, oops! I also tried by replacing `Subsystem ...` by `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` but the result was the same: `friend` cannot connect the server anymore via SFTP.

**Question:**

**How to to isolate user `friend` so that he cannot go out of his home `/home/friend/` via SFTP/SSH?**

---

Note: I already read [How to Restrict SFTP Users to Home Directories Using chroot Jail](https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-sftp-user-home-directories-using-chroot/), [How can I chroot sftp-only SSH users into their homes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes)
, etc.

Comment: Did you check the log files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Working solution

This is inspired by the tutorial [How to configure an sftp server with restricted chroot users with ssh keys](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2399571)
 mentioned in @HeysusEscobar's answer.

Do this from `root`:

```
useradd friend   # NB: this doesn't create a home dir, see https://askubuntu.com/q/374870
passwd friend    # set the password 
groupadd sftpusers
mkdir /sftp
mkdir /sftp/friend        # this is where he'll be chrooted
mkdir /sftp/friend/home   # his home directory
mkdir /sftp/friend/www    # for websites
usermod -aG sftpusers friend   # aG for append group
chown friend:sftpusers /sftp/friend/home/
chown friend:sftpusers /sftp/friend/www/
usermod -d /sftp/friend/home friend   # set as his home directory
```

Add this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server   # you'll probably need to comment this line
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -d /home
Match Group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
```

and do `service sshd restart`. That's all!

Note that:

- other users can still `ssh`, so it did not modify anything for other users
- user `friend` cannot `ssh`
- user `friend` can connect via `sftp`

PS: if you want to make `friend`'s website available to internet, you can add this to Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName friend.example.com
  DocumentRoot /sftp/friend/www
  php_admin_value "open_basedir" "/sftp/friend"
  <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Site-note: even with `open_basedir` above, can't `friend` still go out of his chrooted-environment with PHP or run malicious code having impact on the whole filesystem? Linked question: [A chrooted/isolated SFTP user can still visit the whole filesystem with PHP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593415/a-chrooted-isolated-sftp-user-can-still-visit-the-whole-filesystem-with-php)

---

## Old (half-working only) solution

Replacing `ChrootDirectory /home/friend` by `ChrootDirectory /home` helped, according to documentation:

> ChrootDirectory: Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication. **All components of the pathname must be root- owned** directories that are not writable by any other user or group.

With this, user `friend` can connect to SFTP again; cannot go out of `/home/`; but can still visit `/home/anotheruser/...`, which is unwanted!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what OS you are using but I use the link below when I have to configure jailed SFTP users. It is a really good tutorial on how to configure a jailed SFTP user.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2399571

I would then mount bind whichever directory to the chroot directory you want to give your friend access to.

Comment: Wonderful, it works!

Comment: There's still a problem: if you follow this tutorial, at the end the SFTP is indeed isolated but you can still access the whole filesystem by using PHP... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593415/a-chrooted-isolated-sftp-user-can-still-visit-the-whole-filesystem-with-php Any idea about that @HeysusEscobar?

Answer (score -2):

You could keep the modifications to your .sshd_config file and use `chmod -R 700 /home/anotheruser` to restrict access to anotheruser's home from anyone else, including `friend`. You could [modify the chmod value](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-700/) if this is too strict, but that is what I personally was looking for in my question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590339/how-can-i-have-a-restricted-ssh-user-without-totally-limiting-ssh-access/590481#590481). (Sorry for posting this as another answer, I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment to your answer)