# How can I have a restricted ssh user without totally limiting ssh access?

Tags: ssh, linux-mint

I am working on making a new user with SSH access to my server for *file sharing purposes* via WinSCP. My goal was to restrict them to their home directory by having their default shell be rbash, but when I do this it won't let me connect to the server and it will stop at the "Connecting to Host..." message. I can connect with this user when the shell is set to the default shell. Is there a permission that I need to modify to get around this?

There is an entry in `/etc/shells` for `rbash`.

edit

Comment: @steeldriver I'm running Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon (Cinnamon version 4.4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to restrict the user by adjusting my .sshd_config [as shown here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561350/415739). This step prevents them from going back into the system files. In addition, I changed the permissions of the other /home/user/ folders with `chmod -R 700 /home/user/`, which stops them from going into other home directories, while still having full descent access within their own.

Answer (score 1):

Shell access typically requires shared system binaries and libraries. Limiting a user to only their home directory is unlikely to be usable (i.e. the user in question won't be able to do much).

If you  want the user to run a certain program, you could set their login shell to that program. Git does this with [git-shell](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell) for example.

In general on a multi-user system, it is a good idea to make home directories not world readable (such as by setting an appropriate `umask`, or adjusting home directory permissions).

Comment: Oops, should have mentioned this in the post: I'm not trying to give the user a lot of capabilities, I would just like them to be able to read and write to their home directory for file sharing. Is there a way for me to use permissions to make the ssh files readable, home directory files readable/writable, and all others restricted?

Comment: https://debian-administration.org/article/94/How_to_restrict_users_to_SFTP_only_instead_of_SSH + set all home directories and sensitive system files to not be world-readable.

Comment: I set the shell just like in the link, but setting the umask to 077 in the user's .profile file doesn't seem to take effect (there is no .bash_profile or .bash_login so it should be using .profile)? I feel like this is so close to what I am looking to do

Comment: Bash reads different startup files in different situations. I personally don't use it for this reason among others. If you want to use bash you could put umask in all of the startup files or source some of the startup files from others. Also, individual programs may override umask.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `/sshchroot/user/user`. `/sshchroot/user` would be owned by root and writable by root only (as `ChrootDirectory` demands) and you would bind-mount `/home/user` to `/sshchroot/user/user`. This way the user does not even see the other home directories.

```
mount --bind /home/user /sshchroot/user/user # can be done in /etc/fstab
```

Comment: It is already in my shells file with:
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/dash